the trait bound `T: spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate` is not satisfied
I am trying to compile an anchor program with the following dependencies and getting a compile time error that I don't know how to resolve, the src/state.rs isn't even part of my code.
Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["idl-build", "init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["idl-build"]}
spl-tlv-account-resolution = "0.8.1"
spl-transfer-hook-interface = "0.8.2"

The error:
   Compiling spl-tlv-account-resolution v0.6.4
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate` is not satisfied
   --> src/state.rs:286:45
    |
286 |         let bytes = state.get_first_bytes::<T>()?;
    |                           ---------------   ^ the trait `spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate` is not implemented for `T`
    |                           |
    |                           required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
note: required by a bound in `get_first_bytes`
   --> src/state.rs:252:5
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
276 |     pub async fn add_to_instruction<T: SplDiscriminate + spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate, F, Fut>(
    |                                                        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate` is not satisfied
   --> src/state.rs:177:40
    |
177 |         let (bytes, _) = state.alloc::<T>(tlv_size, false)?;
    |                                -----   ^ the trait `spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate` is not implemented for `T`
    |                                |
    |                                required by a bound introduced by this call
    |

There's more like these.
Is that a compatibility issue? Running rustc 1.81.0 (eeb90cda1 2024-09-04) but also tested with 1.76 for example and getting the same issue.
Many thanks for helping me troubleshoot this.

Which solana version are you on? Maybe try one of the program esxamples and see if that config there weorks: https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/token-2022/transfer-hook/counter/anchor/programs/transfer-hook/Cargo.toml

That was it, incompatible packages, thanks for the hint @JonasH!

You can find the dependencies of solana crates on crates.io.
For spl-tlv-account-resolution for examples the dependecy would be solana program 2.0.3.

